# Function to check if string is code number or text

Tags: javascript

I have an input return to me two types of value, I want to check if this value is a code number or text.

code number pattern: "847707/926503"
text pattern: "omar atef"

How can I build function work like this?

```
checkValue("847707/926503") // return true
checkValue("omar atef") // return false
```

Comment: what exactly is a "code number"?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Is a code number pattern always in the form of <numbers>/<numbers>?

Comment: yes ,
code number pattern always like that <numbers>/<numbers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the string against a regular expression that checks to see if the string is a pair of six numbers separated by a slash.

```js
const regex = /^(\d{6})\/(\d{6})$/;

function checkValue(str) {
  const match = str.match(regex);
  if (match) return `${str}: true`;
  return `${str}: false`;
}

console.log(checkValue('847707/926503'));
console.log(checkValue(''));
console.log(checkValue('omar atef'));
console.log(checkValue('billy/12345'))
console.log(checkValue('988765/123456'));
console.log(checkValue('847707//926503'));
console.log(checkValue('847707/926503/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like that?

```
function checkValue(input) {
    return /^(\d{6})\/(\d{6})$/.test(input) ? true : /[A-Z]/ig.test(input) ? false : null;
}
```

Comment: Six numbers, not five :) And this will return true for something like `456456/444222/`.

Comment: just fixed that @Andy :)